# JPA - how to reference attributes in queries if AccessType is "property"?

Tags: java, jpa

I would like to have an entity whos attributes are called by JPA per getter methods instead of direct field access. So I use `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)`. Everything's fine so far. But when I specify a `NamedQuery` with referencing the attributes, the following compiler error is shown:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The state field path 'u.password' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
- The state field path 'u.login' cannot be resolved to a valid type.#
```

The code is:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@NamedQuery(name="User.validateLogin", query="SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.login = :login AND u.password = :password")
public class User implements Serializable {
```

Is there a way to set the AccessType to PROPERTY **AND** using queries with references to attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. If you use the default (`AccessType.FIELD`), than a few things happen automatically (you can use the attributes within queries for instance).

If you use **`AccessType.PROPERTY`** then you've to set the Annoation **`@Basic`** in front of the getter methods.